# Como puedo conocer el color de fondo background-color de un textarea con javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

Estimados necesito ayuda para conocer el color de fondo background-color de un textarea con javascript, para luego compararlo .
El color es rgb(204, 204, 204) lo saque mediante inspeccion de la web pero no se como hacerlo automatico.
Gracias

Answer (score 2):

La forma más segura para obtener los estilos de los elementos es mediante [**`getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) , que forma parte de `window`.

Supongamos que el color de fondo es asignado vía CSS, mediante la clase `test`, puedes hacer esto:

```js
/* Seleccionamos el elemento por la clase*/
var elTxt=document.querySelector('.test');
const style = getComputedStyle(elTxt);
const bgColor = style.backgroundColor;
console.log(bgColor);
```

```css
.test {background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); }
```

```html
<textarea class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
```

Funciona también si el estilo es asignado *inline* (no se recomienda asignar estilos inline en los elementos, lo pongo aquí solamente para mostrar que así también funciona):

```js
var elTxt=document.getElementById('mi-txt');
const style = getComputedStyle(elTxt);
const bgColor = style.backgroundColor;
console.log(bgColor);
```

```html
<textarea id="mi-txt" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
```

Comment: tu explicación esta mucho mejor

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo obteniendo el estilo computado del elemento de la siguiente forma:

```
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
window.getComputedStyle(textarea, null).getPropertyValue('background-color')
```